# Tracert shows "Request timed out" for all hops, despite present ICMP replies

Tags: windows, networking, traceroute

When trying to run `tracert -4` for any host, I get `Request timed out` responses for all hops except the target host itself.

I thought there is some problem with my router, but running Wireshark shows that my machine receives *ICMP Time-to-live exceeded* responses for all intermediate echo requests sent. Why is `tracert` unable to show any useful information? Is there some problem with my Windows machine, or is my router or ISP somehow corrupting the packets? How can I check that?

Running `traceroute` from the router to the same host shows all hops correctly. Running `tracert -6` to the same host also shows all hops.

My machine is running Windows 10 x86-64 and my router is running OpenWRT 15.05.1